# call java function from jni Android V4

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

For calling java function's in Android Activity from JNI, I use the following code :

```
    jmethodID messageMe = env->GetStaticMethodID(clazz, "updateStatus", "(IILjava/lang/String;)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clazz, messageMe);
```

it's working perfectly for Android 2.3 but not working for Android 4.0.3, I get this error message 
E/dalvikvm(9341): JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference 0x5b6130b2 (index 19500 in a table of size 125)

so, how can i call correctly java function from jni for both new and old versions

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing in any parameters to `CallStaticVoidMethod` - it's expecting 4 as you can see in the method signature string.

I read in another question this error is caused by passing in an incorrect parameter type:
[Error: JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed stale global reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12071585/error-jni-error-app-bug-accessed-stale-global-reference?rq=1)